# Wireguard VPN Client GUI issue

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, wireguard, free

I am not getting the Wireguard option at Settings > Network > VPN > addnetwork(+). Only PPTP and OpenVPN is visible. How can I add the wireguard option there? Screenshot attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSqFB.png)

I am also getting the error while importing the VPN using conf file the error is attached in snapshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Fbn.png)